# Understanding why $E_{ij}E_{kl} = \delta_{jk}E_{il}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came across this statement in my textbook and I can’t understanding why $E_{ij}E_{kl} = \delta_{jk}E_{il}$

where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker delta: $1$ if $j=k$, $0$ if $j\neq k$.

If $i = 1, j = 3, k=2, l=2$. We get

$E_{13}E_{22}=\delta_{32}E_{12}$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\neq
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

There is no equality here. How am I envisioning this wrongly?

It seems like my textbook is confusing things for me. Here is how they define the "Kronecker delta" and the "E" matrix.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kronecker Delta $\delta_{32}$ is not a matrix, as you pointed out yourself. And all $E_{ij}$ are square matrices.

Comment: Hi! I have updated the questions with the definitions from my textbook, this seems be where my confusion comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\neq
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ the matrices RHS are no square matrices ?????

We have

$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\delta_{32}E_{12}$, since $\delta_{32}=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am obviously confusing things. For example $\delta_{32}$ refers to the value for the matrix $\delta_{ij}$ at row $3$ and column $2$ which is 0. 

But looking at my textbook they define a matrix for $E_{12}$ and not just a value, which seems strange to me?

Answer (score 1):

What $E_{13}E_{22}=\delta_{32}E_{12}$ means is that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\delta_{32}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$since $\delta_{32}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the LHS: $$E_{13}E_{22} = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} = \delta_{32}E_{12}.$$

But if you change $$E_{13}E_{32} = \pmatrix{0&2&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} = \delta_{33}E_{12}.$$